# copy dependency assembly resources to specific folder

Tags: maven

I have ProjectA which uses the Maven assembly plugin to pack some resources from a module into the repository.

I have then ProjectB which has a dependency on ProjectA. In ProjectB, I'd like to use the maven-dependency-plugin to unpack the module resources(packed by the assembly plugin) into some target folder of my choice.

I configured the dependency plugin as following, but when I run maven, it will only copy the module's resources and not also the assembly resources.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>unpack</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <artifactItems>
                    <artifactItem>
                        <groupId>path.to.projectA.groupId</groupId>
                        <artifactId>moduleA</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0</version>                  

                        <outputDirectory>some/path/here</outputDirectory>
                    </artifactItem>
                </artifactItems>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to specify the correct `classifier` and `type` to maven so that it can do this. Your assembly should available in your local repository or downloadable from repository.

For instance, assuming your assembly was named `moduleA-distribution-1.0.zip`, you would alter the above snippet as follows:

```
             <artifactItem>
                    <groupId>path.to.projectA.groupId</groupId>
                    <artifactId>moduleA</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0</version>                  
                    <classifier>distribution</classifier>
                    <type>zip</type>
                    <outputDirectory>some/path/here</outputDirectory>
              </artifactItem>
```

Comment: Thank you!! One minor thing: if the zip contains a folder structure like: moduleA-distribution-1.0.zip!/folder1/folder2, how can I extract everything from folder2 into destination folder? Currently, it will also copy the dir structure along with the files, so it will create some/path/here/folder1/folder2/file.txt